# Why is the time in ubuntu different from that in windows?

Tags: 20.04, windows-10, time

I recently installed ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10 in dual-boot and when I was working with these two operating systems, I understood that the time in ubuntu is not the same as the time in windows. (For instance, The time in ubuntu is 5:30 p.m but in windows, the time is 2:00 p.m.)

So, why is that and is it possible to resolve?